# How do I write a proof for: $\neg p\vdash p\to q$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I haven't seen this question asked here, but I stumbled upon this question while practicing. I couldn't/can't figure it out and it's bugging me, even though it's not mandatory for any exercises, I would still like to know the answer.

The question is, using Fitch-Style logic, prove: $\neg p\vdash p\to q$

I've figured out that this has to do with $\neg p \lor q \equiv p \to q$, but using Fitch-Style logic I'm pretty sure I can't just do the following:

1. $\neg p$
2. $\neg p \lor q \space (\lor Intro \space 1) $
3. $p \to q \space (using \neg p \lor q \equiv p \to q)$

So I figured out that I can do:

1. $\neg p$
2. $\neg p \lor q \space (\lor Intro \space 1) $

From there on I guess I can free $q$, but from there on I am clueless and I've been clueless for almost the entire day. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: It depends on the details of the Fitch system you're using - but overall, the crucial thing to look for is "ex falso quodlibet" or the "explosion principle".  Usually that would be called something like ${\bot}E$ and/or ${\lnot}E$.  So, in order to answer the question, we would need to see the precise rules of the system you're using, especially the parts that involve $\bot$ and/or $\lnot$ symbols.

Comment: I was using this website in combination with an online course I'm following. http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/ This exercise specifically asked for natural deduction using a fitch-style proof.

Comment: Maybe you have to use Ex Falso rule...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof would be correct in some systems, but for the openlogic system, you'll need to use the contradiction:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand what's happening here. Where ¬E 1,2 means the elemination of the negation from 1 and 2, what does X 3 mean? What does the X exactly stand for? Does it just mean you can prove anything from line 3, because you can prove anything from ⊥?

Comment: @Wout 'X' is use of the 'X' rule, listed on the referenced page.

Comment: @Wout  Yes, anything follows from a contradiction $\bot$, and the 'X' rule formalizes that.

Comment: It's the Principle of Explosion, or Ex Falso Quodlibet (EFQ).